# What is an example of nested bounded convex and closet sequence of set in a Banach space with empty intersection?

Tags: banach-spaces

What is an example of nested bounded convex and closet sequence of set in a Banach space with empty intersection?

I cannot imagine an example of that. Thanks.

Comment: The first answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167157/reflexive-banach-spaces-and-the-cantor-intersection-property) gives a general construction.

Answer (score 3):

To give a concrete example (based on Daniel Fischer's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1167182)), consider  $c_0$ (the space of sequences $x_1,x_2,\dots$ converging to $0$, with the supremum norm), and let 
$$
A_n = \{x\in c_0 : \|x\|\le 1,\ \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}x_k\ge 1-1/n \}
$$
This is evidently a nested sequence of nonempty closed convex sets. Yet, $\bigcap A_n$ is empty, since the only element it could conceivably contain, $(1,1,1,\dots)$ is not in $c_0$.